# Moving my project from Objective-C xcode 5.1 to SWIFT and xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5, swift, xcode6

I have a already developing and ios application on xcode 5.1 using Objective-c,

**The Question:**
Can I move this project to work with Swift on XCODE 6 beside keeping my objective-c chunck of code?

Comment: I tried to open the project normaly in Xcode 6, it opens but it doesnt show me swift option

Comment: Try adding a new Swift file to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. I recommend reading this guide https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-XID_0

There are also several WWDC sessions available.